# Getting last modified for every file in a directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to get data for every file in a specific directory. Right now I'm just trying to get last-modified date. It seems like I need to convert this WindowsPath to a string, but I couldn't find any function that would do that.

```
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path

startDir = os.getcwd()

pt = r"\\folder1\folder2"

asm_pths = [pth for pth in Path(pt).iterdir()
            if pth.suffix == '.xml']


for file in asm_pths:
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(file)
    print("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(mtime))
```

Console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daniel.bak\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Crystal Report Batch Analyzer\Analyzer\analyzer.py", line 34, in <module>
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(file)
TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not WindowsPath
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `path` argument to [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.stat) must be a string but you are passing in an instance of [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path). You need to convert `Path` to string using `str`.

```
for file in asm_pths:
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(str(file))
    print("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(mtime))
```

But if you only want last modification date then [`os.path.getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) will be fine:

```
for file in asm_pths:
    print("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(str(file)))
```

Comment: There is no need for the os.stat, pathlib has the same function, and switching between Path object and strings could be confusing

Answer (score 19):

You may also use [`lstat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.lstat) or [`stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) of a `pathlib.Path` object to get a [stat_result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result) object which holds information about the path/file. The last modified date can be calculated from the [st_mtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_mtime), which is:

> Time of most recent content modification expressed in seconds.

### Example:

```
from pathlib import Path

file = Path(r'C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\file.txt')
file.lstat().st_mtime

Output: 1496134873.8279443

import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(file.lstat().st_mtime)

Output: datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 12, 1, 13, 827944)
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to use `os.stat` function, pathlib has the same function- `file.stat()` where file is you path object.
You can use the following code:

```py
for file in asm_pths:
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = file.stat()
    print(f'last modified: {time.ctime(mtime)}')
```

But if you only want last modification date then use this:

```py
for file in asm_pths:
    print(f'last modified: {time.ctime(file.stat().st_mtime)}')
```

I would prefer to avoid using os.path and pathlib.Path in the same project as much as possible in order to prevent confusion and bugs, because pathlib's paths are made of Path objects and os.path is expecting strings as paths.

Comment: When pathlib grows a getmtime equivalent, I'll happily switch over.  Bonus if it returned a properly UTC'd datetime instance. (But that's unlikely, core devs seem to hate timezones… reminds me of the str/unicode mess)

Answer (score 4):

[`os.path.getmtime(file)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) should give you the anwser. Your problem is that `file` type should be a string. Change your code to something like:

```
# a list of string
paths = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith(".xml")]
for f in paths:
    print("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(f)))
```